# Changes not reflected after editing data without manual refresh on angular webapp

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, angular-material

I just edited the Milestone name and changed the flag color to green ,but i should be reflected in real time , but to get result i will have to refresh the page , then i am getting updated data ,
code is in angular in freont end , i am attaching the screenshot of before and after result , and also code of frontend
[i just updated the name of milestone and changed the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFXGj.png)
after refreshing the page , i got result this but i want this result in real time without refreshing the page manually ,
also here is the code of my angular frontend [Code frontend angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7IAv.png)

i am expecting changes in real time, it is currently updating data after manual refresh

here is the .ts file

```html
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AssetServices } from '../../../../../../../../../services/app-asset.service';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatDialogRef,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CreateTaskComponent } from '../../create-task/create-task.component';
import { CreateMilestoneComponent } from '../../create-milestone/create-milestone.component';
import { ILoggedInUser } from '../../../../../../../../../models';
import { StoreService } from '../../../../../../../../../services/store.service';
import { CreateTemplateComponent } from '../create-template/create-template.component';
import { endpoints } from '../../../../../../../../../constants';
import { CommonService } from '../../../../../../../../../services/common.service';
import { NotificationService } from '../../../../../../../../../services/notification.service';
import { TaskService } from '../../../../../../../../../services/task.service';
import { CommonUtils } from '../../../../../../../../../utils';
import { AddTaskToTemplateAndMilestoneComponent } from '../add-task-to-template-and-milestone/add-task-to-template-and-milestone.component';
import { DeleteTaskComponent } from '../../delete-task/delete-task.component';
import { DeleteComponent } from 'src/app/popups/delete/delete.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-detail',
  templateUrl: './template-detail.component.html',
  styles: [],

})
export class TemplateDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  taskList: any[] = [];
  rotateIcon: boolean = false;
  loggedInUser: ILoggedInUser;
  taskAddedToSite: any[] = [];
  showTaskDetails: boolean = false;
  selectedTask: any;
  shouldShowThreeDotsForTask: boolean

  constructor(
    public assetService: AssetServices,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private storeService: StoreService,
    public commonUtils: CommonUtils,
    public commonService: CommonService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private taskService: TaskService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TemplateDetailComponent>
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shouldShowThreeDotsForTask =
      this.data.canViewTemplateTaskDetails ||
      this.data.canEditTemplateTask ||
      this.data.canCreateTemplateTask ||
      this.data.canDeleteTemplateTask;
    this.loggedInUser = this.storeService.authSitennaUser.data.value;
    this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
      this.data.Tasks
    );
  }

  menuClosed(event) {
    this.rotateIcon = false;
  }

  createOrEditTask(task?: any): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateTaskComponent, {
      width: '684px',
      maxWidth: '95vw',
      maxHeight: '95vh',
      disableClose: true,
      data: task
        ? {
            ...task,
            name: task.task_name,
            fromTemplate: true,
            assessment_organization_id: this.loggedInUser.user.organization_id,
            milestones: this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList,
            assessment_id: this.data.site.assessment_id
          }
        : {
            assessment_organization_id: this.loggedInUser.user.organization_id,
            milestones: this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList,
            fromTemplate: true,
          },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async (result) => {
      if (result.task) {
        const payload = {
          ...result.task,
          template_id: this.data.id,
        };
        try {
          this.commonUtils.showLoader();
          const response = task?.id
            ? await this.taskService.updateTemplateTask(task.id, payload)
            : await this.taskService.createNewTemplateTask(payload);
          // result.files = result.files.filter(file => !file.id);
          // if(result.files.length) {
          //   const payload = {
          //     entity_id: response.id,
          //     entity_type: 'Task',
          //     files: result.files
          //   }
          //   const docResponse = await this.commonService.sendFormData(
          //     endpoints.uploadTaskDocuments,
          //     payload
          //   );
          //   response.Document = [ ...docResponse, ...response.Document];
          // }
          if (task?.id)
            this.data.Tasks[
              this.data.Tasks?.findIndex((value) => value.id === task.id)
            ] = response;
          else this.data.Tasks.push(response);
          this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
            this.data.Tasks
          );
        } catch (e) {
          this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
        } finally {
          this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
        }
      }
      if(result.milestone) {
        this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList = [ ...result.milestone ];
      }
    });
  }

  editTemplate(template: any) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateTemplateComponent, {
      width: '684px',
      maxWidth: '95VW',
      maxHeight: '95vh',
      disableClose: true,
      data: template,
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.data = { ...this.data, ...result };
      }
    });
  }

  async deleteTemplate(template: any) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteTaskComponent, {
      width: '464px',
      maxWidth: '95vw',
      maxHeight: '95vh',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { name: template.name, type: 'Template' },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async (value) => {
      if (value) {
        try {
          this.commonUtils.showLoader();
          await this.taskService.deleteTemplate(template.id);
          this.dialogRef.close({
            delete: true,
            milestone: this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList,
            taskAddedToSite: this.taskAddedToSite,
          });
        } catch (e) {
          this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
        } finally {
          this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  createOrEditMilestone(data?: { milestone?: any; taskList?: any[] }) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateMilestoneComponent, {
      width: '876px',
      maxWidth: '95vw',
      maxHeight: '95vh',
      disableClose: true,
      data: data?.milestone
        ? {
            ...data.milestone,
            taskList:
              (data?.taskList?.length && data?.taskList) ||
              this.taskList
                .filter((task) => task[0] !== 'milestone')
                ?.map((task) => task[1]),
          }
        : {
            taskList:
              (data?.taskList?.length && data?.taskList) ||
              this.taskList
                .filter((task) => task[0] !== 'milestone')
                ?.map((task) => task[1]),
            organization_id: this.loggedInUser.user.organization_id,
          },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result.milestone && data?.milestone) {
        const index = this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList.findIndex(
          (data) => data.id === result.milestone.id
        );
        if (index !== -1) {
          this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList[index] = result.milestone;
        }
      } else if (result.milestone && !data?.milestone) {
        this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList.push(result.milestone);
      }
      if (result.removedTask && result.removedTask.length) {
        this.data.Tasks = this.data.Tasks?.map((task) => {
          if (result.removedTask.indexOf(task.id) !== -1) {
            task.milestone_id = null;
          }
          return task;
        });
        this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
          this.data.Tasks
        );
      }
      if (result.task && result.task.length) {
        this.data.Tasks = this.data.Tasks?.map((task) => {
          if (result.task.indexOf(task.id) !== -1) {
            task.milestone_id = result.milestone.id;
          }
          return task;
        });
        this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
          this.data.Tasks
        );
      }
    });
  }

  addTaskToNewMilestone(task: any | any[]) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateMilestoneComponent, {
      width: '876px',
      maxHeight: '95vh',
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        fromTemplate: true,
        task: (Array.isArray(task) && task) || [task],
        taskList: [],
        organization_id: this.loggedInUser.user.organization_id,
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result?.milestone) {
        this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList.push(...result.milestone);
      }
      if (result?.removedTask && result?.removedTask.length) {
        this.data.Tasks = this.data.Tasks?.map((task) => {
          if (result.removedTask.indexOf(task.id) !== -1) {
            task.milestone_id = null;
          }
          return task;
        });
        this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
          this.data.Tasks
        );
      }
      if (result?.task && result?.task.length) {
        this.data.Tasks = this.data.Tasks?.map((task) => {
          if (result.task.indexOf(task.id) !== -1) {
            task.milestone_id = result.milestone[0].id;
            task.Milestone = result.milestone[0];
          }
          return task;
        });
        this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
          this.data.Tasks
        );
      }
    });
  }

  addTaskToTemplateOrMilestone(task: any, type: string = 'Milestone') {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddTaskToTemplateAndMilestoneComponent, {
      width: '684px',
      maxHeight: '95vh',
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        fromTemplate: true,
        task,
        dropdownData: this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList,
        type,
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.data.Tasks = this.data.Tasks?.map((task) => {
          if (task.id === result[0]?.id) {
            task.milestone_id = result[0].milestone_id;
            task.Milestone = result[0].Milestone;
          }
          return task;
        });
        this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
          this.data.Tasks
        );
      }
    });
  }

  async duplicateTask(task: any): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.commonUtils.showLoader();
      const response = await this.taskService.createNewTemplateTask(task);
      this.data.Tasks.push(response);
      this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
        this.data.Tasks
      );
    } catch (e) {
      this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
    } finally {
      this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
    }
  }

  deleteTaskDialog(task): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteTaskComponent, {
      width: '464px',
      maxHeight: '95vh',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { name: task.task_name },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((value) => {
      if (value) {
        this.deleteTask(task.id);
      }
    });
  }

  async deleteTask(id: string) {
    try {
      this.commonUtils.showLoader();
      await this.taskService.deleteTemplateTask(id);
      this.data.Tasks.splice(
        this.data.Tasks.findIndex((task) => task.id === id),
        1
      );
      this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
        this.data.Tasks
      );
    } catch (e) {
      this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
    } finally {
      this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
    }
  }

  async removeATemplateTaskFromAMilestone(id: any){
    try {
      if(id){
        const payload = {
          id: id,
          milestone_id: null
        }
        this.data.Tasks?.map((task) => {
          if(task.id === id){
            task.Milestone = null;
            task.milestone_id = null;
          }
        });
        this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
          this.data.Tasks
        );
        await this.taskService.updateTemplateTask(id, payload);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', error.message);
    }  finally {
      this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
    }
  }

  async deleteTaskFromMilestone(milestone: any) {
    if (milestone?.task?.length) {
      const payload = milestone?.task.map((task) => {
        task.milestone_id = null;
        return this.taskService.updateTemplateTask(task.id, task);
      });
      try {
        this.commonUtils.showLoader();
        const response = await Promise.all(payload);
        milestone.task?.forEach((value) => {
          value.milestone_id = null;
          delete value.Milestone;
          const index = this.data.Tasks.findIndex(
            (task) => task.id === value.id
          );
          if (index !== -1) {
            this.data.Tasks[index] = value;
          }
        });
        this.taskList = this.taskService.changeListAccordingToMilestone(
          this.data.Tasks
        );
        this.notificationService.get_Notification(
          'success',
          'Milestone deleted from the Site.'
        );
      } catch (e) {
        this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
      } finally {
        this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
      }
    }
  }

  async addMilestoneToSite(milestone: any) {
    if (milestone?.task?.length) {
      const payload = milestone?.task.map((task) => {
        task.name = task.task_name;
        task.entity_id = this.data.site.id;
        task.entity_type = this.commonService.taskConfig.find(
          (value) =>
            value.name === 'Site Assessment Site' &&
            value.type === 'entity_type'
        )?.id;
        return this.taskService.createNewTask(task);
      });
      try {
        this.commonUtils.showLoader();
        const response = await Promise.all(payload);
        this.taskAddedToSite.push(...response);
        this.notificationService.get_Notification(
          'success',
          'Milestone added to the Site.'
        );
      } catch (e) {
        this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
      } finally {
        this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
      }
    }
  }

  async addTaskToSite(task: any) {
    try {
      task.name = task.task_name;
      task.entity_id = this.data.site.id;
      task.entity_type = this.commonService.taskConfig.find(
        (value) =>
          value.name === 'Site Assessment Site' && value.type === 'entity_type'
      )?.id;
      this.commonUtils.showLoader();
      const response = await this.taskService.createNewTask(task);
      this.taskAddedToSite.push(response);
      this.notificationService.get_Notification(
        'success',
        'Task added to the Site.'
      );
    } catch (e) {
      this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
    } finally {
      this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
    }
  }

  checkTemplateTaskBeforeAddToSite() {
    if (!this.data?.Tasks?.length) {
      let dialogRef = this.dialog.open( DeleteComponent, {
        width: '464px',
        maxWidth: '95vw',
        maxHeight: '95vh',
        panelClass: 'bg-dark-blue',
        disableClose: true,
        data: {
          header: ( `Add Template to Site` ),
          content: `You are adding an empty template. This will not effect the tasklist on site. Are You Sure?`,
          cancelButtonText: ( 'No' ),
          button: ( 'Yes' ),
        },
      } );
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe( async ( result ) =>
      {
        if(result) {
          this.addTemplateToSite();
        }
      })
    }
    else if(this.data?.Tasks) {
      this.addTemplateToSite();
    }
  }

  async addTemplateToSite() {
   const payload = this.data?.Tasks.map((task) => {
     task.name = task.task_name;
     task.entity_id = this.data.site.id;
     task.entity_type = this.commonService.taskConfig.find(
       (value) =>
         value.name === 'Site Assessment Site' &&
         value.type === 'entity_type'
     )?.id;
     return task;
   });
   try {
     this.commonUtils.showLoader();
     let response = await this.taskService.createNewTask(payload);
     response = response.map((task, index) => {
      return {
        task,
        ...this.data?.Tasks[index]
      };
     })
     this.taskAddedToSite.push(...response);
     this.notificationService.get_Notification(
       'success',
       'Template added to the Site.'
     );
   } catch (e) {
     this.notificationService.get_Notification('error', e.message);
   } finally {
     this.commonUtils.dismissLoader();
   }
  
  }

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close({
      template: this.data,
      milestone: this.data.assessmentSiteMilestoneList,
      taskAddedToSite: this.taskAddedToSite,
    });
  }

  showOrHideTaskDetails(taskDetails) {
    this.selectedTask = taskDetails;
    this.showTaskDetails = !this.showTaskDetails;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code as code, not as image. Also, actual ts code would be useful too.

Comment: i am not able to post code here , can you please tell me how can i share .ts file and . html file?

Comment: posted typescript code here, now waiting for your response

Comment: hello, Misha Mashina , please look into this matter , it is very important project , i need to submit it by today , otherwise company will take fine from me , so please help me now